# I want to play a video in a div popup after a user clicked on a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello I have a generated table within PHP.
The code finds video folders within each folder video and creates a table with some data and a hyperlink to the video files.

```
<table id="mediatbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Hall</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $directory = "./media/week/";
        $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
        // Scan all weekly folders
        foreach ($scanned_directory as &$week) 
        {
            $mediafiles = $directory."/".$week;
            // Scan all the mediafiles in the weekly folder
            $dir = new DirectoryIterator($mediafiles);

            foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) 
            {
                if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) 
                {
                    $mediafile=$fileinfo->getFilename();
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$week</td>
                            <td>Unknown</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class=\"btn\" data-popup-open=\"popup-1\" href=\"#\">$mediafile</a></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>Unknown</td>
                        </tr>";

                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I have found some nice snippet online that triggers a div popup.

```
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>    
    $(function() {
        //----- OPEN
        $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //----- CLOSE
        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

There is some css, but I don't think it will contribute to the answer (I might be wrong).
What I want to achieve is simply pass the link to the file into the popup withint a nice play, it can be HTML5 video tag or anything else.
I have fiddled some time and I can not find a way to make it work. 
My javascript skills are low, I would like to learn more.

Does anyone have a nice idea? Solution? Pointer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you  (because of long text i can not write it as a comment)

Change your open code block to this:

```
//----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        var targeted_popup_link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').append('<video controls="controls" width="400" height="280"><source type="video/mp4" src="'+targeted_popup_link+'"></video>');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Hello @Farzin Kanzi, 

Your line of code works, I see what it does, it passes the HREF value from the clicked link into a variable. Later on the videotag gets inserted into the popup with the link.
The only problem I have is that the video fills the entire page, the popup with the close button does not appear or is being overshadowed by the video tag.

Comment: Hi! I do not know your `js` library and I assume that `$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]')` is an empty element, So I set it's html and you will not have the close button any more. If you want it you must set it back to the html(): `.html('<video>.....</video> <PUT YOUR Close Button HERE>')

Comment: All the js is within the page. There is no external js other than jQuery.

Comment: Ok. Now you can use `append()` instead of `html()` that adds the video to the div without removing another children of the div. I update my answer.